# Using a variable to name a new text file

Tags: vbscript, text-files

I have a small script that I want to find the computers name, and create a text file in the flash drive the script will run from named after the PC's name.

So far I can pull the name into a variable, and create a text file with a string literal argument. but If I try to pass the name into `GetFileName` and `GetAbsolutePathName` calls it either gives me an error or gives the file a blank name.

**Edit:** I have updated the code to the full code. The program is intended to get the Windows license keys on all the computers in the labs I manage for easy reference. I apologize if the issue is simple, this is my first script I have written, and I feel like it is something I just seem to be missing.

The code in question:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ConvertToKey(WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId"))
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
strComputerName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%COMPUTERNAME%" )

Function ConvertToKey(Key)
  Const KeyOffset = 52
  i = 28
  Chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
  Do
    Cur = 0
    x = 14
    Do
      Cur = Cur * 256
      Cur = Key(x + KeyOffset) + Cur
      Key(x + KeyOffset) = (Cur \ 24) And 255
      Cur = Cur Mod 24
      x = x - 1
    Loop While x >= 0
    i = i - 1
    KeyOutput = Mid(Chars, Cur + 1, 1) & KeyOutput
    If (((29 - i) Mod 6) = 0) And (i <> -1) Then
      i = i - 1
      KeyOutput = "-" & KeyOutput
    End If
  Loop While i >= 0
  ConvertToKey = KeyOutput
  Dim filesys, filetxt, getname, path
  Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set filetxt = filesys.CreateTextFile("I:\"& strComputerName & ".txt", True)
  path = filesys.GetAbsolutePathName("I:\"& strComputerName & ".txt")
  getname = filesys.GetFileName(path)
  filetxt.WriteLine(KeyOutPut)
  filetxt.Close
End Function
```

The result is a text file named ".txt" in the correct location.

Comment: There isn't any obvious error in your code unless you don't have proper rights on that drive to create a file or your machine names contains illegal characters (highly unlikely). Have you tried checking the values of `strComputerName`? Have you defined `wshShell` correctly?

Comment: Did you use On Error Resume Next ? did you declare this variable wshShell ? 

You should edit your question and add the hole code !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass `strComputerName` into the function, and preface the call with the `Call` keyword.

Comment: The `Call` keyword is only required if you use parentheses around the arguments. This would work as well: `ConvertToKey WshShell.RegRead("..."), WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%COMPUTERNAME%")`. Or you could have moved `strComputerName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%COMPUTERNAME%")` *before* calling `ConvertToKey`. The issue you had was because you used the variable `strComputerName` before it was actually defined.